# jQuery Combo Boxes (User Selection) / Text Validation

Tags: jquery, combobox, autocomplete, selection, validation

Is there a way to have a text validation tool for jQuery such that:

Box 1: Hi
Box 2: Automatically fills with Hi if Hi is entered in Box 1

In another case if,

Box 1: Bye
Box 2: If the user enters Bye in Box 2 it says that they entered an invalid response

Also is it possible to have it such that if Choice A is selected in a a combo box it auto fills some of the text boxes and prevents the user from editing them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at jQuery event handlers at [jQuery Events/Bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind).